# Allow Linux developers to work remotely on Linux dektops

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, eclipse, java

My users run either Linux or Windows desktops. They have servers allocated to them with all the internal tools available (for building, running internal applications, ...).

Windows users would use Exceed on Demand to login into the Linux server and run Eclipse/Intellij from there. Linux users would use X-forwarding to run Eclipse/IntelliJ (or Exceed on Demand for Linux). The problem is Linux users have a horrible experience with X-forwarding or Exceed on Demand. So much that we are considering scraping Linux desktop altogether.

My users want to run Eclipse/IntelliJ on the server with good performance. What would be my choice aside from X-forwarding?

Comment: why must the editor run on the server?  It's usually much more efficient to transfer just the files.  Even better if you use some version control system.

Comment: Our internal tools are only provisioned on the servers due to legal issues. These servers are more like work servers that are provisioned to a group of developers. They are not computing/infrastructure servers.

Answer (score 2):

Use e.g. [FreeNX](http://freenx.berlios.de/) on the server (comes with many distributions) with e.g. the [OpenNX](http://opennx.net/download.html) client on Windows. Works like a charm.

NX sits on top of the X protocol and renders the "X-perience" more bearable.

Comment: +1 for the beautify wordplay. And for NX. ;-)